# What's goin' with Youtube under Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: 15.10, youtube

guys!
I have problems to access youtube. Returns "Server not Found".
What can I do to solve this?
I wish a happy new year for all of us!
Tks,
Fernando

Comment: Where are you located, and how you connected to the network? Youtube is often blocked by firewalls etc as it is not often used for productive stuff.

Comment: What's the output of `host youtube.com`, `host youtube.com 8.8.8.8` and `ping -c4 youtube.com` (use `ping6` instead, if you're in an IPv6 network)?

Answer (score 0):

Server not Found means there's some problem between your computer and the youtube server that is keeping you from finding the destination server.  I just tested youtube, and it's not currently broken, so I suspect it's a DNS issue.

Try accessing youtube by IP Address instead to see if this is the case.

So try this addresses and see if you get access to youtube directly...

```
http://208.65.153.238
http://208.65.153.251
http://208.65.153.253
http://208.117.236.69
```

Source: http://compnetworking.about.com/od/traceipaddresses/f/youtube-ip-addr.htm

Comment: Oh, Tks dear friend! The IP adresses returns me the Google site only.

Comment: Apparently this is because Google owns Youtube, and makes my answer unuseful.  Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142030/why-does-the-resolved-ip-of-youtube-com-direct-to-google-com

Comment: Can you access Youtube with another machine on your network?